# When running "tsc --version" on the command line, what is the source of the tsc@2.0.4 package's output?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, npm-install, tsc

## System information:

```
$ uname
CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19045 # Windows 10

$ node --version
v18.17.1

$ npm --version
9.6.7
```

## Steps to reproduce

When I run `npm i -D tsc@latest && npx tsc --version`, it gives me this output:

```
$ npm i -D tsc@latest && npx tsc --version

changed 1 package, and audited 834 packages in 3s

# ...
# npx tsc --version output:


                This is not the tsc command you are looking for


To get access to the TypeScript compiler, tsc, from the command line either:

- Use npm install typescript to first add TypeScript to your project before using npx
- Use yarn to avoid accidentally running code from un-installed packages

$ npm ls
# ...
├── tsc@2.0.4
# ...
```

According to [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc), the `tsc` repository is at https://github.com/basarat/tsc

## The question

I can't find where this "This is not the tsc command you are looking for" message--or any other part of it--comes from. How do I find it so I can submit a PR to reword it?

## What I've tried

- I've searched throughout the source code using github.com's <kbd>/</kbd> shortcut.
- I've searched throughout the source code using github.dev's <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> shortcut.
- I've looked in the package.json

I was about to search `npm` documentation to see if it automatically generates this based off of some setting, but then I realized I have no idea if `npm` is the place to look. I didn't want to potentially waste a day(s) barking up the wrong tree.

---

PS: I've figured out why I'm getting this error (I was supposed to install `typescript`, not `tsc`). That's not related to my question.